# Shifting Ubuntu HDD to new PC

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, hard-drive, clone

I have a **relatively very old PC**: **Compaq m2000** (Intel Celeron M 360
) with just **256 MB** of RAM. I was thinking of installing **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** on a portable drive on a newer PC and then using it on this Laptop.

**My questions is:** Will installing Ubuntu from another PC cause problems like **wrong drivers** and other **configurations** like screen resolution, WiFi card change, different speaker configurations, or will Ubuntu install appropriate drivers on first boot or later on when shifted?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure how Ubuntu would handle it, it might be able to auto-detect, BUT the amount of RAM doesn't live up the recommended amount:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't suit well on too old machines. For those i would suggest a debian installation, which uses less ram memory than Ubuntu.

But if you try it anyway, it would really face all those problems you mentioned, which demands reconfiguration.